# TypeError: squares.slice is not a function on trying to make a copy of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component in react, I am trying to make a copy of an array. But the function keeps failing on the point when I actually call the slice method. Here's my full code for better context

```
const Board = ()=>{

    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill("")) 
    const [isX , setIsX] = useState(true)
    const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0)
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null)
    console.log(`squares is ${Array.isArray(squares)}`, squares.slice())

    const onClick = (i)=>{
        console.log("On CLick")
        if(winner || stepNumber>9) return;
        console.log(squares)
        const newSquares =  squares.slice()
        (isX) ? newSquares[i] = "X" : newSquares[i]= "O"
        setIsX(!isX)
        
        setWinner(newSquares)
        if(winner){
            console.log(winner)
        }
        setSquares(newSquares)
        setStepNumber(stepNumber+1)

    }
    return(
        <div className = "board">
            {squares.map((square , i) => {
                return(
                    <Square key={i}  data-key={i} value={square}
                    onClick = {()=>onClick(i)} />)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The line where I declare newSquares keeps failing with the error:`TypeError: squares.slice(...) is not a function` . Can somebody please tell what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the output of squares `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

Comment: what does this console? console.log(squares)

Comment: it logs an array

Comment: add that array to the code so we can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a one-line conditional statement, you are doing the assignment wrong. The problem is in this line:

```
(isX) ? newSquares[i] = "X" : newSquares[i]= "O"
```

Change that to:

```
newSquares[i] = isX ? "X" : "O"
```

#### Suggestion

Instead of `.slice()` I would change the `newSquares` like this:

```
const newSquares = squares.map((sq, index) => index === i ? (isX ? "X" : "O") : sq)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, do you know the reason why though? The logic checks out. according to me it'll first check if the value of isX is true and if true it will assign the value accordingly

Comment: won't it take more time than just a simple shallow copy and index assignment?

Comment: It is just syntetichally wrong, one-line conditional statement expects you to return something, not assign.

Comment: I suggested that because it is a common way of updating the array, it won't take more time, since `slice` does almost the same thing. Nothing wrong with your way of doing it though.

Comment: My bad, it didn't allow me to that time